# Bash error when trying to pipe output: Syntax error

Tags: bash, sh

I have a bash script (`test.sh`) with the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

npm test |& grep -v '[HPM]'

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
...
```

When trying to run this script locally I get this error:

```sh
test.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
test.sh: line 3: `npm test |& grep -v '[HPM]''
```

Comment: Are you just running the script like `./test.sh`?

Comment: Don't use the `|&` syntax.  Your life will be much easier if you use `npm test 2>&1 | grep ...`

Comment: ...and your life will be even easier if you do `npm test | grep` and don't modify stderr.

Comment: No @0x5453. Doing `sh test.sh`. Whenever I try `./test.sh` it says `no such file or directory`.

Comment: Well, that's why. `|&` is bash syntax, not sh.

Comment: See: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: @WilliamPursell `npm test 2>&1 | grep -v '[HPM]'` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|&` syntax is using a non-standard token which is recognized by `bash` but not all shells.  Such a construct is often called a `bashism`. If your shell is inadvertently invoked as a non-bash shell, then it is a syntax error.  You can easily use a standardized construct for this:

```
npm test 2>&1 | grep -v '\[HPM\]'
```

Note that this is unusual.  It seems odd to capture the stderr of npm, but perhaps you really do want to check if `grep` prints any lines.  There's really no need to explicitly check `$?`, and your code would normally be written:

```
if ! npm test 2>&1 | grep -v '\[HPM\]'; then
    : grep failed.  Do something 
fi
```

But again, this seems strange.  `grep -v` will "fail" if it does not print any lines of text, and it will succeed otherwise.  Perhaps you were expecting `$?` to contain the exit status of `npm` in your original code, but it does not.  `$?` will be zero if `grep` prints any text, and non-zero otherwise.

Comment: `npm test` starts a server and then runs integration tests. In some instances, [HPM] errors are printed in the terminal. To hide these errors, I am using `2>&1 | grep -v '[HPM]'`. Do you have any other suggestions as to hide these errors? Also, answering your question about `$?`, I am expecting it to contain the exit status of `npm test ...` but youre right that it does not. Do you know how I could check the exit status of npm test?

Comment: You could do: `if ! npm test; then ...; fi 2>&1 | grep -v '[HPM]'`, but that gets a little clumsy with any other errors.  Probably better to do something like `{ if ! npm test; then ....; fi 2>&1 >&3  | grep -v '[HPM]' >&2; } 3>&1`...but really it's best to not try to filter the HPM errors!  Fix them instead.

Comment: Also note that `grep -v '[HPM]'` will also filter the line the just contains `H`.  You probably meant `grep -v '\[HPM\]'`